# Display additional user fields

Tags: php, custom-field, users, registered

A theme is in development that echo's fields from the users account on their themed account page. This is the standard format.

```
<?php echo  $current_user->user_lastname;?>
```

Thats all well and good. But there are 13 additional fields added via the plugin register plus. How do we echo them? This for example does not work.

```
<?php echo  $current_user->user_post_code;?>
```

Any help appreciated, marvellous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Robin I Knight:**

Have you tried this?

```
<?php echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'user_post_code',true);?>
```

Comment: Ive been a dammed fool and not entered any info on those fields. Utter whit nit. Sorry

Comment: @Robin I Knight - So did my answer address your question? If yes, please vote up and accept otherwise future people finding this answer won't know if it solves the question or not. If it did not answer, please elaborate so, again, future readers will be helped by our collective efforts.